# How to restrict internet access to other computers in my network

Tags: networking, server, internet

I have already configured Ubuntu server 18.04 to work as a DHCP server. I also set the default gateway of my other computers in the network to the DHCP server.

My question is,  how I can manage other computers internet access, for example blocking social media or restrict access to only business web sites ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to use a proxy in your computer. 
https://www.varonis.com/blog/what-is-a-proxy-server/

Maybe you can get more information on the internet

Hope it is helpfull for you

Comment: As above, some sort of proxy is needed. I use Pi-Hole https://pi-hole.net/ It was easy to install and setup for me on Ubuntu. Has a local web-based interface for settings/monitoring, pre-defined ad/malware blocking blacklists etc. etc. Worth a look.

Comment: Thanks Jose, can you please share with me how to setup and configure

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways to do that:

1. Through the router's firewall, this can restrict access to sites determined by IP or domain name.
2. through a proxy server, this is a more flexible and efficient method, there are several proxy servers such as (** squid **) this aplication is free the only price is time to configurated, but is able to optimized traffic through a buffer in your proxy server wich provide to clients the access to determinated web stored in proxy server, also restrict access to a web pages wich you determined in a file, access through credentials, access reports, and many other functions, i recommend.

Upgrade:

Well to configure router is diferrent for any router, usually you have to access to a administrator page of router.
the direction most common is:

> 192.168.1.1

In there you have to access to firewall rule or block domaind.

For **Squid** is a little more complicated, first you have to install squid with

> sudo apt-get install squid3

After you have to access to the configuration file:

> /etc/squid/squid.conf

And modify parameters what you needs,
add this line in your squid.conf

> acl forbidden dstdomain "/etc/squid/forbidden_domains"

After that make a file named forbidden_domains an then add you block domains in the file like this:

```
.facebook.com
.twitter.com
.pinterest.com
.pinterest.cl
.radios.com.bo
```

After that you have to restart the squid server, but if you need more details you have to search the squid information in youtube or google, there are many information only you have a patience for condigutare like you need is not a thing out of this world. regards.

Comment: Thanks Roberto, Can you please share with me how to setup and configure in both options, hope that I'm not asking for much :) other wise you can share with me some good resources to count on to increase my learning curve .. Thanks a lot

Comment: I hope this information can help you, regards.

Comment: Thanks Roberto, for router\firewall blocking please be informed that I already make Ubuntu server to act as a router\firewall to my network so if you have detailed guide how to restrict access to websites I will be much appreciated .. for squid configuration this should be configured in a separate machine other than the one which configured as a router\firewall correct ?